# Make use of wrong label in learning?

Tags: noise, multilabel

I have a dataset. Each sample has two labels. The labels in the first set are mostly correct (>90%). The other labels, say annotated by an inexperienced annotator, are mostly incorrect, but they are definitely random mistakes. They represent intelligent guess from nearby classes.

For example, an image of a zebra has correct label as "Zebra", but the second label is "Horse", which is another class in my data set.

I'm thinking these two labels could form some sort of trajectory to learn, or the second label represent a confusing label that I should penalize. Are there any related papers that I could take a look at? Many thanks.

Comment: How do you know which ones are the mistakes?

Comment: The results of the inexperienced annotator are reviewed by the "trained" annotator, so I can assume the first set of labels are more reliable.

Comment: So why use incorrect labels at all? Why not use the annotations by the experienced annotator?

Comment: Well for one thing, the data set is difficult and the trained annotator could also be wrong. For another, just wondering if the "not-so-wrong" labels could be useful at all.